# String formula for linear models

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a string formula with the independent variables that are significant within my linear model, though I'm finding it difficult trying to include the `+` at the end of each variable.

I have tried:

```
as.formula(sprintf("encounter ~  %s",
                   names(tbest$model)[-1]))
```

However, this only gives the first variable:

```
encounter ~ open_shrubland
```

> Warning message:
> Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1.
> Consider formula(paste(x, collapse = " ")) instead.

How would I include all of them such that: `encounter ~ X1 + X2 + X3 ...`, also, can this be made functional, such that if I wanted to remove a variable, I would only have to do `my.formula[-3]` to remove it?

list of variable names:

```
c("open_shrubland", "Appalachian_Mountains", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
"Central_Hardwoods", "Piedmont", "wetland", "Badlands_And_Prairies", 
"Peninsular_Florida", "Central_Mixed_Grass_Prairie", "water", 
"New_England_Mid_Atlantic_Coast", "grassland", "mixed_forest", 
"cropland", "Oaks_And_Prairies", "Eastern_Tallgrass_Prairie", 
"evergreen_needleleaf", "year", "pland_change", "evergreen_broadleaf", 
"Southeastern_Coastal_Plain", "Prairie_Potholes", "Shortgrass_Prairie", 
"urban", "Prairie_Hardwood_Transition", "Lower_Great_Lakes_St.Lawrence_Plain", 
"mosaic", "Mississippi_Alluvial_Valley", "deciduous_broadleaf", 
"deciduous_needleleaf", "barren")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reformulate` will be helpful.

```
reformulate(names(tbest$model)[-1], 'encounter')
```

If the list of variable names are in `x` :

```
reformulate(x, 'encounter')

encounter ~ open_shrubland + Appalachian_Mountains + Boreal_Hardwood_Transition + 
    Central_Hardwoods + Piedmont + wetland + Badlands_And_Prairies + 
    Peninsular_Florida + Central_Mixed_Grass_Prairie + water + 
    New_England_Mid_Atlantic_Coast + grassland + mixed_forest + 
    cropland + Oaks_And_Prairies + Eastern_Tallgrass_Prairie + 
    evergreen_needleleaf + year + pland_change + evergreen_broadleaf + 
    Southeastern_Coastal_Plain + Prairie_Potholes + Shortgrass_Prairie + 
    urban + Prairie_Hardwood_Transition + Lower_Great_Lakes_St.Lawrence_Plain + 
    mosaic + Mississippi_Alluvial_Valley + deciduous_broadleaf + 
    deciduous_needleleaf + barren
```

Comment: That works great! and If i want to remove `x` variables, I'll just remove them within ```names(tbest$model)[-x]```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a formula with `paste`

```
as.formula(paste('encounter~', paste(names(tbtest$model)[-1], collapse = "+")))
```